# How can I restrict modalViewController in Landscape?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am working on iPad application where I am showing some view in modalView controller.
In Landscape, when I click on `UITextField` for taking some input modalview controller goes up and keyboard appears.
But I have changed the height of modalViewController and I dont want the modalView goes up for keyboard. How can I do this? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In the UIViewController's code, where you move its modalViewController, check if the interface orientation is not landscape

```
if(([self.interfaceOrientation!=UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft])
     &&([self.interfaceOrientation!=UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]))
//your code to repostion the view controlled by the modalViewController
```

Comment: It is not about orientation. ModelViewController is having its default property to scroll up if UIKeyboardWillShowNotification occurs in Landscape.
I want to restrict this behavior.

Comment: It's better use the `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(<#orientation#>)` to check landscape orientation, but the question is about how to disable modal VC going up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use custom presentation code. You cannot change the scrollup behaviour, when the keyboard appears.

You could add a 1024*768 sized black transparent view on top of the window and then your view on top of this. But you would have to build your own borders around your view in that case. Probably there are some open-source implementations of a modal popover. You can search for that on cocoacontrols etc.